# pyglet.graphics: IndexError on ctypes array creation

Tags: python, debugging, opengl, ctypes, pyglet

I'm developing a small game with pyglet. One centerpiece is, of course, drawing coloured rectangels. I initially did this by creating images in memory and `blit()`ing them, which worked fine. After noticing how ugly, roundabout and inefficent (yes, I profiled - `ColorRect.draw()` took significant time and became 10x more efficent through this change) this is, I've started creating vertex lists instead, via `pyglet.graphics.Batch` (I copied most of the code verbatim from one of the examples). Since then, I experience a weird exception in some low-level OpenGL code that I failed to find a cause for or reproduce reliably.

There is no apparent relation to gameplay events -- as in, nothing exceptional happens just before, or I constantly miss it. As the error occurs somewhere deep in the event loop, I cannot easily track down which position update causes it. Honestly, I'm stumped. Thus I'll braindump what I have found out and hope for some kind psychic.

I've tried it out on Windows 7 32 bit (I may get around to try it on Ubuntu 11.10 soon) with Python 3.2.2, with a pyglet revision 043180b64260 (pulled from Goggle Code and built from source, the 1.1.4 release is harder to install as it doesn't run 2to3 automatically, though it appears to be equally py3k-ready). I'll probably update to the latest mercurial version next, but it's only a few commits and the changes seem entirely unrelated.

The full traceback (censored some paths out of principle, but note it's in its own virtualenv):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<my main file>", line 152, in <module>
    main()
  File "<my main file>", line 148, in main
    run()
  File "<my main file>", line 125, in run
    pyglet.app.run()
  File "<virtualenv>\Lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\__init__.py", line 123, in run
    event_loop.run()
  File "<virtualenv>\Lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\base.py", line 135, in run
    self._run_estimated()
  File "<virtualenv>\Lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\base.py", line 164, in _run_estimated
    timeout = self.idle()
  File "<virtualenv>\Lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\base.py", line 278, in idle
    window.switch_to()
  File "<virtualenv>\Lib\site-packages\pyglet\window\win32\__init__.py", line 305, in switch_to
    self.context.set_current()
  File "<virtualenv>\Lib\site-packages\pyglet\gl\win32.py", line 213, in set_current
    super(Win32Context, self).set_current()
  File "<virtualenv>\Lib\site-packages\pyglet\gl\base.py", line 320, in set_current
    buffers = (gl.GLuint * len(buffers))(*buffers)
IndexError: invalid index
```

Running with post-mortem (actively stepping through code until it happens used to be infeasible as the FPS went from 60 down to 7) `pdb` shows:

- `buffers` is a list of ints; I have no idea what these represent or where they come from, but they are pulled from a list called `self.object_space._doomed_textures` (where `self` is an window object). The associated comment says this block of code releases texture scheduled for deletion. I don't think I explicitly use textures anywhere, but who knows what pyglet does under the hood. I assume these integers are the IDs or something of the textures to be destroyed.
- `gl.GLuint` is an alias for `ctypes.c_ulong`; Thus `(gl.GLuint * len(buffers))(*buffers)` creates an `ulong` array of the same length and contents
- I can evaluate the very same expression at the `pdb` prompt without errors or data corruption.

Independent experiments (outside the virtualenv and without importing pyglet) with ctypes shows that `IndexError` is raised if too many arguments are given to the array constructor. This makes no sense, both experimentation and logic suggest the length and argument count must always match.

1. **Are there other cases where this exception may occur?** May this be a bug of pyglet, or am I misusing the library and missed the associated warning?
2. Would the code which creates and maintains the vertex lists be of any use in debugging this? There's probably *something* wrong with it. I've already stared at it, but since I have little experience with `pyglet.graphics`, this was of limited use. Just leave a comment if you'd like to see the `ColorRect` code.
3. Any other ideas what might cause this?

Comment: Can you make shure no multithreading is used? That may cause problems in `base.py` if multiple threads are active. The `buffers` may be changed by another thread while the array is allocated before the individual GLuint constructors are run to fill it. Thus `len(buffer)` would'nt match `(*buffers)` length.

Comment: @dronus Devious idea! I'm not using threads anywhere, and I doubt pyglet tries to run in parallel. But I'll check if `'_thread' in sys.modules`.

Comment: @dronus Forget about `_thread`, it's apparently always imported (I checked in a freshly interpreter session). `threading` on the other hand is imported in my code but not in an interpreter sessions. `threading.enumerate` gives merely `[<_MainThread(MainThread, started 4256)>]` though. I'll add an assertion that this is always true, and investigate who imported `threading`.

Comment: @dronus It seems `logging` import `threading`. `pyglet.app.base` does too but apparently it only uses `threading.Event` and `queue` (which in turn imports `dummy_threading` which imports `threading`) for single-threaded management. The process explorer also indicates there's a single `python.exe` thread all the time.

Comment: Also, the logging should not interfere with this `base.py` code. And it is unusual to do any multithreading in OpenGL control code as that usually isn't needed and needs passing around the thread associated GL context.

Comment: I am not shure how pyglet works, but problems may depend on the event loop model of the OS. If for example, your program does its drawing in a timed main loop, ints may added to the `self.object_space._doomed_texture` there by the draw code. However `set_current` and thus the excepting line may be called by OS event callback on Window's readraw demands or something else. But that should show up with your assertion either I hope.

Comment: @dronus Yes, I think this would probably involve a second Python thread, triggering the assertion anyway. Besides, I *believe* pyglet has its own event loop and polls for OS events on every opportunity. A glance over `pyglet.app.win32.Win32EventLoop` supports this view, it creates an event queue and when the (single-threaded) event loop is running, it gets some messages from that queue, one-by-one, and acts on them. By the way, thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Well then I am at lost.. maybe a bug in python itself on this Windows build.

Comment: Sorry, not a solution here I think, just some notes: **1)** Question and comments are talking about `_doomed_textures` but I think must be about `_doomed_buffers` **2)** `IndexError` appears because code try to allocate a buffer with less elements than the original one, is that correct? (question says "...too many arguments...") **3)** Call my attention the line 373 of `pyglet.gl.base.py` ending with `... and False:`, so code never calls `glDeleteBuffers`. I will like try to remove that last condition and test it again (work around?).

Comment: @JuanMellado 1) Yes. 2) That seems to be the case. 3) Never noticed, will check.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to provide a really relevant answer since there is no code provided but from what I can see from the error output.

```
buffers = (gl.GLuint * len(buffers))(*buffers)
```

So if I understand correctly, you are multiplying the size of an GLuint (4 bytes) with your actually buffers length (if initialized). Maybe that's why your Index is invalid, because it is too high?

Usually it would be ok since a buffer is in bytes, but you said that it is a list of ints?

Hope it helps

Comment: My understanding of ctypes is that `some_c_type * some_int` creates a type of `some_int` items of type `some_c_type` (note that `GLuint is c_ulong`). For instance, `c_long * 10` yields `<class '__main__.c_long_Array_10'>` and this class can be instanciated with `10` arguments. Trying to instanciate it with 11 or more parameters leads to an `IndexError`, passing out-of-range values simply truncates silently (try `(c_byte * 10)(*range(4000, 4010))`).

Comment: I've looked a bit more into ctypes, they are saying this. [Quote from](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) "Note: Some code samples reference the ctypes c_int type. This type is an alias for the c_long type on 32-bit systems. So, you should not be confused if c_long is printed if you would expect c_int — they are actually the same type." I don't know how relevant this page could be for you, but I bet it is the same for uint and ulong.

Comment: Well I mean, it doesn't really matter then (the type of GLuint), but I still don't see (if buffers is a list of ints of the same type) why you would need to multiply the size of this type with your array length. From what I can see of the code it is hard for me to help you more than that. I can only suggest to be more doubtful about pyglet and do more test in a standalone project to investigate about that (with your virtualenv and pyglet imported).

Comment: Multiplying the type with the buffer length produces a ctypes array, which seems to be required for passing the integers to OpenGL. I appreciate your help, but you seem to be off track. Yes, I also fear pyglet might be at fault. But as I already managed to achieve similar improvements through other means, I'm not exactly keen on spending even more time on this issue.